# How to Create a Global Function then use on Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-variables

Im From VB.net base want to learn ASP.NET MVC

For Example : Function created below (how to create in global folder/cs and how to call it then use in Controller)

```
Function pRound(Number ,NumDigits) 
    Dim dblPower, vPSTEmp, intSgn

    dblPower = 10 ^ NumDigits
    vPSTEmp = CDbl(Number * dblPower + 0.5)
    pRound = Int(vPSTEmp) / dblPower
End Function
```

For vb I just add <--#include file="include/**function**.asp"-->

then can use it like pRound(number, 4)

Please Teach Me How to Do it. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a new class file in your solution and make a static class;

```
namespace ProjectName.Functions
{
   public static class Utility
   {
      public static float pRound(float number, int digits){
         float result = 0;
         // your code here
         return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your controller, since a static class is instantiated at the start of the program, you could just call it;

```
using ProjectName.Functions;

public ActionResult TestController
{
   // call Utility.pRound(), no need to instantiate the class
   float round = Utility.pRound(1,1);
}
```

Comment: i added new class in folder(Functions) then add using projectName.Functions; but still got bug (Utility doesnt not exist in the current context)

Comment: @JHOng I added a namespace to the answer. Try to rebuild as well before running the program.

Comment: i totally do the same u teach but namespace 'Functions' does not exist in the namespace 'ProjectName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited Jerdine Saibo's answer.
By the time it gets approved, here's an updated code. (pRound methods needs to be static)

```
namespace ProjectName.Functions
{
   public static class Utility
   {
      public static float pRound(float number, int digits){
         float result = 0;
         // your code here
         return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: but my problem is (are you missing an assembly reference?) so the function i can't call.. Im try to fix this . and finding solution on9

Comment: namespace ProjectName.Function will be diffrent for you. Here ProjectName will be your project's name i.e. 'DemoWebApplication'.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper class and call from the controller else another option is that you can create a base controller and implement it in all your other controller, then you can access like base.pRound(1,1);